# Хранение временных данных в ASP.NET Core Web Api без использования Cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Подскажите, есть ли возможность сохранять состояние между запросами на время пользовательской сессии без использования кукис? Например, как сохранить товар в корзине, не записывая его в бд и при этом очищать её, когда сессия пользователя завершена?

Comment: хранить в сессии на серваке?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, да. Временные данные пользователя

Comment: а в чем вопрос?храните в сессии

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, сессия работает посредством куки. Это не подходит

Comment: @Mihail Можно в каждую ссылку добавлять ID сессии, но это довольно костыльный способ.